# Exclusión de una librería heredada en proyecto maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Nunca me había tocado excluir una librería (jar). Me está dando problemas de seguridad la librería heredada org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl y no se está usando en ninguna parte del proyecto.

¿Cómo se excluye una librería para que no la descargue al compilar?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```